# Compilation of pattern failed at LibXML.pm

Tags: perl, html-parsing, libxml2

I'm reading a large HTML file using `XML::LibXML`.
When constructing a pattern like this:

```
XML::LibXML::Pattern->new('//span[@class="entry"]');
```

It gives the following error:

`Compilation of pattern failed at /Users/chris/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.31.3/lib/site_perl/5.31.3/darwin-2level/XML/LibXML.pm line 2138.`

But this one is working fine:

```
XML::LibXML::Pattern->new('//span');
```

I'm not sure if the `[@class="entry"]` part is not supported by `XML::LibXML::Pattern` or I'm just doing it wrong.

Any information is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While a valid *XPath*, that isn't a valid *Pattern*.

> **Patterns are a small subset of XPath language**, which is limited to (disjunctions of) location paths involving the child and descendant axes in abbreviated form as described by the extended BNF given below:
>
> ```bnf
> Selector ::=     Path ( '|' Path )*
> Path     ::=     ('.//' | '//' | '/' )? Step ( '/' Step )*
> Step     ::=     '.' | NameTest
> NameTest ::=     QName | '*' | NCName ':' '*'
> ```
>
> For readability, whitespace may be used in selector XPath expressions even though not explicitly allowed by the grammar: whitespace may be freely added within patterns before or after any token, where
>
> ```bnf
> token     ::=     '.' | '/' | '//' | '|' | NameTest
> ```
>
> **Note that no predicates or attribute tests are allowed.**

(Emphasis mine.)